# How to toggle slices of multiple images with another image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that when each image slice is clicked, it will change to a different picture (which is the picture behind that picture). I am also trying to make it toggle also.

Here is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div id="first-wrapper">
            <img src="img/cat0.png" cat-pic-src="cat0.png" alt="cat picture 0">
            <img src="img/cat1.png" cat-pic-src="cat1.png" alt="cat picture 1">
            <img src="img/cat2.png" cat-pic-src="cat2.png" alt="cat picture 2">
            <img src="img/cat3.png" cat-pic-src="cat3.png" alt="cat picture 3">
            <img src="img/cat4.png" cat-pic-src="cat4.png" alt="cat picture 4">
        </div>
        <div id="second-wrapper">
            <img src="img/ninja0.png" ninja-pic-src="ninja0.png" alt="ninja picture 0">
            <img src="img/ninja1.png" ninja-pic-src="ninja1.png" alt="ninja picture 1">
            <img src="img/ninja2.png" ninja-pic-src="ninja2.png" alt="ninja picture 2">
            <img src="img/ninja3.png" ninja-pic-src="ninja3.png" alt="ninja picture 3">
            <img src="img/ninja4.png" ninja-pic-src="ninja4.png" alt="ninja picture 4">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-wrapper {
 width: 970px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 500px;
 margin: 2px 200px;
}


#first-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
}

#second-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block; 
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('img').click(function(){
    $(this).toggle().css('z-index', '10');

    });

});
```

It's not working as I had expected to, when I click on the image each block that I click on just disappears.

For example, if I were to click on the image "cat0.png", it would replace it with "ninja0.png" (depending on which image I click on), and if I clicked on image "cat1.png" it would replace it with "ninja2.png" and so on. I would like it if I was also able to toggle this action as well.

Keep in mind that each image is stacked on top of each other.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve so I suggest you create a jsfiddle to demo your issue. And regarding disappearing of your picture - that's because you do ```toggle()``` which shows or hides the element.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added some more examples.

Comment: I think you may have a problem with the markup that you have used: because the images in each `div` wrapper are not stacked one upon another but are stacked upon a `div` that is stacked upon another `div`. If the images were stacked directly on top of one another then the solution is fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do, as mentioned your intention is not very clear?

There are also other (possibly better) ways to do this.

```js
var mainWrapper = document.getElementById('main-wrapper'),
    catImgs = [].slice.call(mainWrapper.getElementsByClassName('cat')),
    ninjaImgs = [].slice.call(mainWrapper.getElementsByClassName('ninja'));

mainWrapper.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    var target = evt.target,
        classList = target.classList;

    if (classList.contains('cat')) {
        classList.toggle('hidden');
        ninjaImgs[catImgs.indexOf(target)].classList.toggle('hidden');
    } else if (classList.contains('ninja')) {
        classList.toggle('hidden');
        catImgs[ninjaImgs.indexOf(target)].classList.toggle('hidden');
    }
}, false);
```

```css
#main-wrapper > .cat,.ninja {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
}
.cat {
    position: relative;
}
.ninja {
    position: relative;
    top: -500px;
}
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <img class="cat" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/1" alt="cat picture 0">
    <img class="cat" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/2" alt="cat picture 1">
    <img class="cat" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/3" alt="cat picture 2">
    <img class="cat" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/4" alt="cat picture 3">
    <img class="cat" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/5" alt="cat picture 4">
    <img class="ninja hidden" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/1" alt="ninja picture 0">
    <img class="ninja hidden" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/2" alt="ninja picture 1">
    <img class="ninja hidden" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/3" alt="ninja picture 2">
    <img class="ninja hidden" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/4" alt="ninja picture 3">
    <img class="ninja hidden" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/5" alt="ninja picture 4">
</div>
```

Update: A direct conversion to jQuery

```js
var $mainWrapper = $('#main-wrapper');
    $catImgs = $mainWrapper.find('.cat'),
    $ninjaImgs = $mainWrapper.find('.ninja');

$mainWrapper.on('click', 'img', function (evt) {
    var target = evt.target,
        $target = $(target);

    if ($target.hasClass('cat')) {
        $target.toggleClass('hidden');
        $($ninjaImgs[$.inArray(target, $catImgs)]).toggleClass('hidden');
    } else if ($target.hasClass('ninja')) {
        $target.toggleClass('hidden');
        $($catImgs[$.inArray(target, $ninjaImgs)]).toggleClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

```css
#main-wrapper > .cat,.ninja {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
}
.cat {
    position: relative;
}
.ninja {
    position: relative;
    top: -500px;
}
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <img class="cat" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/1" alt="cat picture 0">
    <img class="cat" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/2" alt="cat picture 1">
    <img class="cat" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/3" alt="cat picture 2">
    <img class="cat" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/4" alt="cat picture 3">
    <img class="cat" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/5" alt="cat picture 4">
    <img class="ninja hidden" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/1" alt="ninja picture 0">
    <img class="ninja hidden" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/2" alt="ninja picture 1">
    <img class="ninja hidden" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/3" alt="ninja picture 2">
    <img class="ninja hidden" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/4" alt="ninja picture 3">
    <img class="ninja hidden" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/5" alt="ninja picture 4">
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, however do you know how to do this using the jQuery library?

Comment: It's a very simple conversion, the syntax is almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `$.toggle()`! May be you can try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').click(function(){
    $('#main-wrapper > div').css('z-index', '5');
    $(this).closest("div").css('z-index', '10');
  });
});
```

```css
#main-wrapper {
  width: 970px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 2px 0;
}


#first-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: -10px;
  z-index: 5;
  margin: 0 200px;
}

#second-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <div id="first-wrapper">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/1" cat-pic-src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/1" alt="cat picture 0">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/2" cat-pic-src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/2" alt="cat picture 1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/3" cat-pic-src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/3" alt="cat picture 2">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/4" cat-pic-src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/4" alt="cat picture 3">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/5" cat-pic-src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/5" alt="cat picture 4">
  </div>
  <div id="second-wrapper">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/1" ninja-pic-src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/1" alt="ninja picture 0">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/2" ninja-pic-src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/2" alt="ninja picture 1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/3" ninja-pic-src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/3" alt="ninja picture 2">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/4" ninja-pic-src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/4" alt="ninja picture 3">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/5" ninja-pic-src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/5" alt="ninja picture 4">
  </div>
</div>
```